# Saving user selected gallery image in ImageView

Tags: android, image

The goal of this activity is to allow the user to enter information and select an image from their gallery to display in an ImageView.

Here is my code for selecting the image.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECTED_PICTURE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[]projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(yourSelectedImage);

                iv.setBackground(d);

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but the photo goes away as soon as the user leaves. I need to be able to save the image path so I can call it on create, automatically setting the ImageView to the image they selected.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this methods:

*public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)*

and

*public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)*

They let you to save your state before onDestroy() and then restore it after onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
 public void openGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

And in onActivityResult add this block:

```
if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri=data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        //iv.setRotation(90);
    }
```